Not getting 502 error page on web server failure
I am running a web server using golang net/http (no tomcat / nginx used here) on an ec2 in a target group assigned to a ALB with SSL.
I want to use a cloudfront distribution, which is already set up for my s3 origin, to display an error page when the golang package is not responding.
I have an error page hosted on the EC2 instance (/fixedresp.html) and I have tried setting up a custom origin (test.my-site-domain.com) as well as a LB origin. I don't believe the origin should be LB based as I have host header rules equal to a sub domain which redirects to a corresponding target group / I need to target the subdomain as origin (please correct me if the origin should be the LB).
A 502 error on the application is not responding with the error page no matter what options I select. I am assuming this may be because there is no web server that is serving the fixedresp.html file.
This is a general guidance question and not a, "things aren't working as they should be" question. I'm just a ID10T member trying to figure things out.
Help would be greatly appreciated!

"I am running a web server using golang net/http ...  there is no web server that is serving the fixedresp.html file" I'm not sure how a static file is supposed to generate a 502.  Are you matching that route in Go and generating a 502?  Please show the relevant parts of the go code.

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil))
This is the only relevant go code. Nothing is serving the file. The 502 is generated by default as a response from the Ec2 instance when the go application is not running. I want to use an error page for this

Thanks, that helps.  You can do this at the CloudFront layer (https://repost.aws/questions/QUwPMsqyDiQqKJYeEvHGwzDw/load-balancer-custom-error-page) or you can do it with a server between the LB and Go.  I would do it in cloudfront.  The article also mentions API Gateway but I wouldn't add that service into your flow just for a custom 502.

Okay, so my CF origin is now tfl-lb-*********.my-region-1.elb.amazonaws.com, my error page response path is /prefix/to/fixedresp.html (and the file has been uploaded to s3). I am still seeing the default 502 when I stop the golang app. Can you please help me understand the response path of the error page? What is this response path relative to? I have 2 origins (One for the LB & one for the s3 bucket). Is the response path either of those? I am new to CF.

Is s3 default origin?

There is no "Default" option when setting up an origin. What do you mean by default?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Here's what you need to do.

Create an S3 bucket to host the custom response page.  Upload the custom page to the path you'll use in the custom status code handling below.
Add that S3 bucket as an origin to the distribution.  Use "Origin access control settings (recommended)" and copy the bucket policy it gives you.
Allow Cloudfront to access the s3 bucket: Go back to the bucket, paste in the bucket policy it gave you.
Create a behavior for the custom response path to route to the S3 origin
Once that deploys, you should be able to test S3 access by hitting the s3 origin path on the cloudfront server.
Configure the error handler to be invoked on the given error - so for you, it sounds like 502 (though when I test this with an empty load balancer target group, I get 503s from the load balancer)


Steps 2-3 have already worked for content that I am already serving through CF. Instead of step 1, I am using this already existing content bucket. I have added a behavior for the response path directly to the fixedresp.html (/posts/images/fixedresp.html). My error page (step 6) is configured with the same response path. Still not getting the page when trying to access the subdomain.my-custom-domain.com
